# How to use PXSelect to filter on more than one element?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use PXSelect to pull a value that's specific to an item and warehouse. I think I've tried every combination and I'm certain that I'm just missing some formatting.

The following code works, but doesn't add a filter for SiteID, which is what I need.

```
INItemSite TheItemSite = PXSelect<INItemSite, Where<INItemSite.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INItemSite.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, TheRow.InventoryID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an "and" with the condition on SiteID like below:

```
INItemSite TheItemSite = PXSelect<INItemSite, Where<INItemSite.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INItemSite.inventoryID>>, 
          And<INItemSite.siteID,Equal<Required<INItemSite.siteID>>>>>.Select(Base, inventoryID,siteID);
```

Another way to get the record by keys will be to use the `PK` of the record.
Below is the `PK` of the `INItemSite`.

```
    public class PK : PrimaryKeyOf<INItemSite>.By<INItemSite.inventoryID, INItemSite.siteID>
    {
        public static INItemSite Find(PXGraph graph, int? inventoryID, int? siteID)
        {
            return PrimaryKeyOf<INItemSite>.By<INItemSite.inventoryID, INItemSite.siteID>.FindBy(graph, inventoryID, siteID);
        }
    }
```

You can write selects by Primary Key like below:

```
INItemSite record = INItemSite.PK.Find(graph, inventoryID, siteID);
```

Comment: Also if accessing by the keys in newer versions you can use the following simplify:  var result = INItemSite.PK.Find(Base, inventoryID, siteID);